# jquery 3 ajax().fail(jqXHR) status is always 0

Tags: jquery, ajax

When maintaining my (old) web app I found out that error handling stopped working, probably already some time ago. Here is my old code which was working:

```
$.ajax({
  url: this.url,
  type: 'post',
  data: jsonsendobject,
  dataType: 'json',
  crossDomain: true, // comment this out when not in test mode from foreign webapp
  xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }, // comment this out when not in thest mode from foreign webapp

  }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    // do something after it worked

  }).fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {

    console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
    // now always returns: {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}             

  });
```

Now jqXHR always returns 0, even if the server obviously sends a 500 status code.

I searched a lof of questions here at stackoverflow but most of them were asked around 2011 and the quality of answers unfortunately is bad. Here are different opinions I read:

- jquery as of 2.0 (of 3.0) does not support the jqXHR object anymore. It is returned for compatibility reasons but status is always 0.
- jqXHR object is empty when used with HTTP 2.0
- HTTP status codes don't work if dataType is "json" (or "jsonp")
- HTTP status codes do not work if it is crossDomain (or a local web app)

But if I read the documentation (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) I cannot find evidence that one of these answers is correct,

I understand that I could probably do something like this

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert( "page not found" );
    }
  }
});
```

But I'd rather like to get the status code and decide after (together with other parameters) what to do about it.

What is the working, non-deprecated way of getting the status code within the .fail() call?

Comment: _"I cannot find evidence that one of these answers is correct"_ - jQuery is open-source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery

Comment: @Andreas I updated the question for easier understanding. Obviously, I tested it and it did not work for me, that is why I am asking for a working solution that is non-deprecated. Your comment about looking into the source code is useless. If you are bored by my question, then don't waste your time.

Comment: Why is it useless? You have a bunch of possible answers and you don't know which one is correct. The definitive answer can be found in the [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) and that's available for everyone.

Comment: @Andreas It is the same as if you had a question about classical latin syntax and my answer would be: "Read the speeches of Cicero, there you will find the answer."